# Magento Category Model not working

Tags: php, magento, categories

Im doing a mass category insert by iterating over a mysqli result set , all the variables used in the code are correct but for some reason my code will not create the category:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');

                try{
                    $category->setName($cat['category_name'])
                         ->setUrlKey(str_replace(" " , "-" , strtolower($cat['category_name'])))
                         ->setIsActive(1)
                         ->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS')
                         ->setStoreId(0)
                         ->setPath('1/2')
                         ->save();

                }catch(Exception $e)
                {
                    die($e->getMessage());
                }

                    if($category->getId() == 0): die("Category Didnt Save!"); endif;
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Is there any error message or it didn't pass in "catch" ?

Comment: no , no exception was thrown, no warnings

Comment: You only get "Category Didnt Save!", that's it ?

Comment: Thats what I got it to output if the category id is 0 after "supposedly" saving